# Get URL of current page from Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

How do I determine the URL of the current page from within Flex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ExternalInterface (`flash.external.ExternalInterface`), you can execute Javascript in the browser.
Knowing this, you can call

`ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString");`

to get the current URL (note that this will be the page url and not the .swf url).

hth

Koen

Comment: This is **not** the correct answer, as in most circumstances you are not allowed to execute JavaScript (for example: Kongregate hosted flash.)

Answer (score 24):

Let's be clear here.

**1.** If you want the URL of the loaded *SWF* file, then use one of these.

Inside your application:

```
this.url;
```

From anywhere else:

```
Application.application.url; // Flex 3
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.url; // Flex 4
```

If you are loading your SWF inside another SWF, then keep in mind that the code above will give different values. `this.url` will return the url of your SWF, where as `Application.application.url` will give the url of the parent/root SWF.

**2.** If you want to know the URL that is in the *browser address bar*, then use one of these.

BrowserManager method(Make sure you have the History.js included in your wrapper html for this to work):

```
var browser:IBrowserManager = BrowserManager.getInstance(); 
browser.init();
var browserUrl:String = browser.url; // full url in the browser
var baseUrl:String = browser.base; // the portion of the url before the "#"
var fragment:String = browser.fragment; // the portion of the url after the "#"
```

JavaScript method:

```
var browserUrl:String = ExternalInterface.call("eval", "window.location.href");
```

If you are parsing the url for parameters, don't forget about this useful function:

```
// parses a query string like "key=value&another=true" into an object
var params:Object = URLUtil.stringToObject(browserURL, "&");
```

Answer (score 8):

From the Application:

```
var myUrl:String = Application.application.url;
```

Answer (score 4):

I searched and came up with [this url](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=deep_linking_7.html).  I've honestly never used Flex, but it looks like the important part of that document is this:

```
private function showURLDetails(e:BrowserChangeEvent):void {
  var url:String = browserManager.url;
  baseURL = browserManager.base;
  fragment = browserManager.fragment;                
  previousURL = e.lastURL;                

  fullURL = mx.utils.URLUtil.getFullURL(url, url);
  port = mx.utils.URLUtil.getPort(url);
  protocol = mx.utils.URLUtil.getProtocol(url);
  serverName = mx.utils.URLUtil.getServerName(url);
  isSecure = mx.utils.URLUtil.isHttpsURL(url);        
}
```

Either way, good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

From the Application, use: this.loaderInfo.loaderURL

to break it apart and use parts of it do:

```
var splitURL:Array = this.loaderInfo.loaderURL.split('/');
var baseURL:String = "http://"+splitURL[2];
```

Comment: I suggest using URLUtil for this purpose: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/URLUtil.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried the e:BrowserChangeEvent version and inside my class it didnt or wasnt the appropriate moment for this event to work so in short it didn't work !

Using Application.application.loaderInfo.loaderURL is my preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString");
```