# Cannot retrieve the browser URL for Mac OS users with Flex

Tags: apache-flex, macos, url

I have a very weird problem.
I'm developing a very simple flex application on Windows 7 64 Bits.
It retrieves the user url and then show it:

```
   public var bm:IBrowserManager;
    protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
      bm= BrowserManager.getInstance();
      bm.init();
      Alert.show("Your URL is : " + bm.url);
    }
```

On my Windows 64 Bits machine (Chrome, FF), it works fine and returns the URL.
But, when I run my project on a Mac OS X machine (Safari, Chrome, FF) : it shows:

```
Alert.show(Your URL is : Null);
```

I think that it cannot retrieve the browser instance or cannot init the browser manager.
I don't know.

Is it a known problem? Is it related to the OS? Is there a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: What's the point of this?  Also, this question has been repeated time and time again.  Please search before posting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get URL of current page from Flex 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425141/get-url-of-current-page-from-flex-3)

Comment: @J_A_X: Did you read the question carefully? I know how to retrieve the URL, but on Mac OS it returns a null string.

Comment: Did you look at the original question and tried that?

Comment: Yes I did. What line in my code is missing comparing to the original question? And above all, my code is working. The only problem is that on Mac OS X, it's not working! It seems that the BrowserManager cannot retrieve the browser instance. I don't want to use external javascript stuff.

Comment: If it's "working" why is it "not working"?  What a conundrum you have.  Anywho, if you look at how to use the BrowserManager in the documentation, it will tell you that you don't want any information until the url actually changes (since the BrowserManager isn't created yet).  Your best bet is to use external javascript.  It'll work every time unless JS is disabled.

Comment: As I said, I would like to male it work with the BrowserManager. Then, as I said it at least 4 times, it works on Windows but not in Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember having a problem with browser manager before too. Try moving the getInstance() outside of the function call. I think I remember that fixed it for me.

i.e.

```
public var bm:IBrowserManager = BrowserManager.getInstance();
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
  bm.init();
  Alert.show("Your URL is : " + bm.url);
}
```

If that fails, try moving the `init()` outside of the handler as well. That could be asynchronous for Mac.

Comment: How would you put the "init()" outside?

Comment: You could put it on the creationcomplete of the app or  somewhere like that. I'm assuming `public var bm:IBrowserManager = BrowserManager.getInstance();` didn't work.